# trying to install openSuse Leap 15.3 alongside existing windows10 on my surface pro

Tags: windows, partitioning, opensuse, dualboot, microsoft-surface-pro

[Device Spec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kqKW.png)

[Windows Spec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqbzV.png)

[Disk Partition in Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5QwL.png)

Now, when I restart and boot using a openSuse Leap 15.3 bootable USB, i expect to see a 100 GB disk that I could partition as required (root, home, swap etc). However, I see two disks of 470 GB, the meaning of which I dont understand. And worried that continuing with the opensuse recommendation will delete 400 GB of my data.

[Opensuze recommendation, where I expect it to talk about the 100 GB of unallocated disk space. Instead it says delete the partition of 470 GB, which I do not know where it appeared from based on the disk partition I am seeing in Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05ybO.jpg)

[Upon trying to modify the partitions using opensuse expert partitioner, this is what I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfRUj.jpg)

I would like to keep my windows10, install opensuse on the 100GB unallocated space and be able to dualboot. I have absolutely no experience installing OS or disk partitions. Please advice.

Comment: In Windows (1) disable Fast Startup (2) temporarily disable Bitlocker. However, if your computer uses some not (yet) supported drive mode in Linux - "RAID, Intel RST, ... - it may not be enough. In that case you need to install AHCI support in Windows then change to AHCI mode in UEFI ("BIOS") and hope for the best.

Comment: Actually I found the reason for this to be "Windows Storage Spaces" which as I understand is a pooled storage made up of two physical drives in my case [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQIDF.png). Any thoughts anybody?

Comment: It's a Microsoft proprietary technology, also not supported. That's all.

Comment: What do you mean not supported? U are saying I cannot install another OS on the machine?

Comment: No, not exactly. I'm saying that if you want to have a proper dual-boot there are conditions you need to met and understand the limitations.